# .htaccess Wordpress Category - redirecting to homepage

Tags: php, wordpress

My .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>
```

Im getting redirect to HomePage but only on one wordPress category. Problematic category is airlines.
url/airlines/test/

Had this line previously in .htaccess, but deleted.

`#RewriteRule ^airlines/(.*)/(.*).png$ ./upload-router.php?folder=$1&airline=$2 [L`]

Also rebuilder permaLinks.

**I can fix this bug by changing  /%category%/%postname%/
to /%category%xxx/%postname%/**, but ofcourse I need how it was original.

I can also FIX it by renaming category to airlines2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. Large project and somehow there was conflict between slugs. Sorry for inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

It might be simpler to use `wp_redirect()` to redirect the category.

```
function redirect_airlines_category() {
    if (is_category( 'airlines' ) && !is_single()) {
        $new_url = "http://frontpage";
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'redirect_airlines_category');
```

Place this in your functions.php, change *frontpage* to the url of your front page, and queries to the category page should get redirected.

Comment: is_category gives false for every category on my page.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update the permalink setup after updating the .htaccess file, it should fix your issue.

Comment: tried several times. stil getting problem. and only on one of all categories.